# Error "Too few nodes"

Tags: dc, components, ltspice, converter, texas-instruments

I got the spice model of component LM2842X on http://www.ti.com/product/LM2842/toolssoftware. When I run the simulation I get a "Too few nodes" error.

The suitable image is attached.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you use the unencrypted version of it?

Comment: yes i used unencrypted version  and i had an error "missed the value of R"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran a simulation with this [model](http://www.ti.com/lit/zip/snvm906), and it seems to work fine:

[image: Circuit]
[image: waveform]

The capacitor values were reduced in order to speed up the simulation. But it seems to produce the required regulated output voltage.

Comment: did you use the component LM2842 from TI?

Comment: Can you transfer the file.lib please?

Comment: @Jack Follow the link that vtolentino posted at the top of the awnser.  Then follow the directions at https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html  Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you help me to solve this problem?

I can't be absolutely sure but, you appear to have got the 2 pins labelled FB and SW swapped AND you omitted the all important flyback diode: -

[image]

I'm not saying that your LM2842 spice model (internally) hasn't got problems but, I am saying that what you have drawn is sooooo wroooooong! Fix it then try again.

Comment: i don't understand what do u want to explain me.

Comment: I believe I've done my explanation.

Comment: The symbol does not necessarily need to reflect the symbol in the datasheet. It is often the case that the Spice symbols are drawn in a way that is it easier to connect in the circuit. As long as the symbol pin numbers match the ones from the netlist, it should work alright.

Comment: @ Andy It didn't work

Comment: Hmm down vote blight. I provide absolutely valuable information that I clearly state may not (but could be) the reason for the problem and I get a down vote. The questioner asked  "*Can you help me to solve this problem*" and I've helped for sure (even if it's not that obvious at this moment in time) so, who(TF) thinks I should be down-voted because of this?

Comment: @Andyaka I totally agree with you, your answer was very informative and had the correct fix, you did not deserve the downvote, the OP's question and behavior deserve it.